# PHP Fatal error: Mage_{mymodule}_Helper_Data not found

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have created my own shipping method with a custom module.
I have tested it on my staging copy of my website and it works perfectly.
But for some reason, the same code doesnt work on my production website.

The error that I found is:

> "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Ship_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 549,"

The worse is that I dont use any helper in my module. I have created it only to respect the normal flow of magento modules.

This is a snapshot of my config.xml

```
 <global>
    <helpers>
        <ship>
            <class>Excellence_Ship_Helper</class>
        </ship>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

And this is my helper Data.php file: (as you can see, very simple)

```
class Excellence_Ship_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

I have refresh the Magento Cache, I have deleted the Helper block on my config.xml and refresh again the cache but the problem persist.

Comment: It looks like your code is calling `Mage::helper('ship')` somewhere, or it's being called in a `module="ship"` property somewhere.

Comment: Can you confirm you can see your module in the System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced grid?

Comment: @MCMXCII . Sure. I have my module activated on this section.

Comment: @MCMXCII I have search on all my code if I use  Mage:helper('ship') but it't not used.

Comment: Can you follow the error stack trace back to see which file made the helper call?

Comment: Might be worth reading through this too. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/magento-fatal-error-class-mage-giftcards-helper-data-not-found-in-app-mag ... Note the answer about the compiler.

Comment: @MCMXCII I will read it. Thanks !

Comment: Can you confirm your helper file is located at: `app/code/local/Excellence/Ship/Helper/Data.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you flushed your Magento & Browser Cache? If not, please do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer my question. I resolve that recompiling all Magento scopes.

[image]